# Find likely maximum distance from center of gaussian sphere in high dimensions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am testing a clustering algorithm in high dimensions. I want to see how it behaves as I allow the clusters to get closer and closer, but it must work perfectly for "well separated" clusters. I need to know how far apart to make those well-separated clusters, a minimum distance L.

My data consists of randomly generated clusters where each point in the cluster equals the center of the cluster plus a randomly generated noise vector. The noise has a Gaussian distribution where each coordinate can vary independently from the others.

If the standard deviation of the variation of each coordinate is S, the number of dimensions is D, and the number of points is N, at what distance L from the center is the farthest point likely to be? If I know that, then the minimum separation between the centers of the clusters that guarantees no overlap is 2*L.

Say I have one dimension. If N = 147,160 points, then I can expect 1 point to be at a distance of 4.5 * S (four-and-a-half standard deviations). For D dimensions, at what factor times the standard deviation am I likely to find the farthest point? I know from this article https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf that the expected value of the radius is

> R = S * sqrt(D)

so it must be farther than that.)

What I need is:

> L = f(N,S,D)

Experimentally (from a C# program), here is an example:

```
N = 53,723 points
S = 30
D = 50 dimensions
L = 262.02 (farthest point from center of any cluster)
```

Comment: How does $N$ compare to $D$?

Comment: Assume that D is between 30 and 5000. Assume N is between 20,000 and 1 million.

Comment: Do you really need the average max deviation or you mostly want to bound probability of max deviation being above some value? For the latter, we know that $R_i^2\sim \chi_D^2$, and we can bound $P(R_i^2>t)<B$ by a Berstein-type consentraction inequality since $\chi^2_D$ is subexponential. Then you can use union bound $P(\max R_i^2>t)<NP(\chi_D^2>t)$ and adjust $t$ based on how small probability of collision you want.

Comment: Sidenote: you should use $S=1$ for reporting simulations results for easier comparison/estimation of order of magnitude. Note that in your simulation, $L/S\approx 8.73$ while $\sqrt {D-1}=7$ so they are pretty close. Also note that $E(R)=\sqrt{D-1}$ while $E(R^2)=D$

Comment: Can you check numerical results you presented? Based on them, $(L/S)^2\approx 76$ while $\chi_{50}^2\approx N(50,100)$, so $76$ would be surpassed many times for $5\cdot 10^4$ samples.

Comment: Here is the best bound I found for the [$P(\chi_k^2-k\geq 2\sqrt{kx}+2x)\leq \exp (-x)$](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4821/92997)

Comment: Yeah, my numbers are odd because I ran with a random value for the standard deviation of each cluster whose maximum value is 30. I will run it again with a fixed value for S to see what changes. It should make L larger.

Comment: Just set $S=1$ for easy analysis of numbers.

Comment: I also got that for $2\log N\ll D$, $E(L^2)\le D+c\sqrt {D\log N}$ for some small constant $c$ (I think $\le 2$).